# Webcam aplication won't close after exitting OPENCV 248 JAVA

Tags: java, opencv, video, netbeans, jpanel

I just finished an app that has a jpanel showing images from the webcam, I used OPENCV 2.4.8 and VideoCapture, when I close the Frame in netbeans the program still keeps running so I have to close it from netbean's stop bottom. I try running the app *.jar in windows the first time it works fine but when I close it and open it again there is a problem with the camara like it is already been use!!! any ideas?

Here is a piece of the code-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Permisos objPer = new Permisos();
    objPer.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    objPer.setBounds(0, 0, 468, 328);
    objPer.setVisible(true);
    objPer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    webFrame panel = new webFrame();
    pan1.add(panel);
    Mat webcam = new Mat();
    video = new VideoCapture(0);
    if (video.isOpened()) {
        while (true) {
            video.read(webcam);
            panel.MatToBufferedImage(webcam);
            panel.setSize(webcam.width() + 40, webcam.height() + 60);
            panel.repaint();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("no video open");
    }

}
```

I GET THE CAMARA TO WORK AGAIN WHEN I UNPLUG IT AND PLUG IT BACK AGAIN TO PC

Comment: You are not releasing the resource(web camera), you have closed the application but web camera is still held back, so when you disconnect it, the process attached to it is closed. Try to release webcam before closing the application.

Comment: Also if your purpose is only to display using usb webcam this site can provide you good [library](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/) for java.

Comment: thanks for the answer, how do a release the resource?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! The class VideoCapture had a function named release(). just needed to add it the exit of the app... Thanks for the Help Mayur!